# Explain about the volatile in this case in java

Tags: java

I have a following code as below:

```
class Example {
    private volatile int testValue = 0;

    public int getTestValue() {
       return testValue;
    }

    public void setTestValue(int testValue) {
       this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    public void increment() {
       this.testValue += 1;
    }
}

class PrintThread extends Thread {
    private Example example;    
    private int x = 0;

    public PrintThread(Example example) {   
       this.example = example;
       x = example.getTestValue();  
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(x != example.getTestValue()) {   // block 1
                System.out.println("printThread: " + example.getTestValue());
                x = example.getTestValue();
            }
        }
    }
}

class IncrementorThread extends Thread {

    private Example example;

    public IncrementorThread(Example example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
          example.increment();
          System.out.println("incrementorThread: " + example.getTestValue());

           try {
              Thread.sleep(800);
           } catch(Exception ex) {

           }
        }
    }
}

public class VolatileExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        new IncrementorThread(ex).start();
        new PrintThread(ex).start();
    }
}
```

When I remove volatile keyword in Example class then I never see the output of PrintThread. In PrintThread when I print out the testValue of example, value of example object still updated but the code in 'block 1' never be executed. Both thread still access the same object, can anyone explain me more detail about this? About the volatile keyword affected in this case

Comment: If you don't use `volatile`, the JVM is free to use thread local storage for `testValue`; as such, you'll never see the result of incrementation. THis is what `volatile` is for: it forces the variable to be re-read on each access

Comment: I must point it out that I disagree with the statemen that "you'll never see the result of incrementation". Ofc that there will be incrementations but eg. in loop with 1M iterations, result of 1M incrementation operations (multi threaded) wouldnt be 1M but less. How much? Nobody knows. 
And I am talking about non volatile variable BUT even with volatile there such operations wouldnt be accurate.

Comment: @Antoniossss the thing is, the memory model doesn't specify the behaviour in the event that `testValue` is not volatile; sure, there _may_ be JVM implementations which will reread each time but it is not required. The semantics of `volatile`, however, are enforced: a write to a `volatile` variable always "happens before" any read of that variable. Which means that eventually the reading thread _will_ see the result of the incrementation. Any JVM must obey this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use atomic integers insteed of volatile fields. To get the idea why that is important try running code below. Here you have 3 types of variables, normal `int`, `volatile int` and `AtomicInteger`. Only `AtomicInteger` assure the thread safety of value. After running this simple code, you will see why.

```
public class Test {

    private int threadCount = 10;
    private int nonVolatileCount = 0;
    private volatile int volatileCount = 0;
    private AtomicInteger atomicCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(threadCount);
    private CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(threadCount);

    private class Task implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            startLatch.countDown();
            try {
                startLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                nonVolatileCount++;
                volatileCount++;
                atomicCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
            endLatch.countDown();
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test().go();

    }

    public void go() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            new Thread(new Task()).start();
        }
        endLatch.await();
        System.out.println("non volatile counter: " + nonVolatileCount);
        System.out.println("    volatile counter: " + volatileCount);
        System.out.println("      atomic counter: " + atomicCount.get());
    }

}
```